# How to make custom spacing for y-axis in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to make a plot in `R` where the spacing between ticks on the y-axis all have the same distance and the tick labels are a custom list of values, for example:

```
set.seed(1)

n <- 10
x <- 1:n
y <- rnorm(n)

plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, ylim=c(-2,2))
axis(1)
axis(2, seq(-2,2,1), c(-100,-10,0,5,1000))
```

gets me a plot where the distance between the y-axis ticks are equal but clearly the true distance between values is not equal, i.e., -100 to - 10 is not the same distance  as 5 to 1000, numerically.

[image]

Now this works, but the problem with this solution is that the data is not correctly mapped to the right position in the plot. As in, I would like for the data to be plotted correctly based on the original scale. So either I need a way to simply change the y-axis to be plotted on a different scale, or for the data to be transformed to a new scale that matches my `axis(2, seq(-2,2,1), c(-100,-10,0,5,1000))` command.

I guess what I am saying is I want the equivalent of `plot(x, y, log = "y")` but I don't actually want the log scale, I just want the tick marks to be even spaced based on values I want shown, i.e., -100,-10,0,5,1000

Comment: can you tell me your desired x and y limits?

Comment: @Damandeep -100 to 1000

Comment: both -100 to 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit hard to implement because you are setting the plot boundaries from -2 to 2 and then wanting axis labels that go from -100 to 1000. It should work if you use `at` and set the boundaries of the initial `plot` to match the `axis` parameters. I've modified your example to spread the data across the plot more evenly:

```
set.seed(1)

n <- 10
x <- 1:n
y <- 100*rnorm(n)

yticks = c(-100,-10,0,5,200)
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, ylim=c(-100,200))
axis(1)
axis(2,at = yticks,labels=yticks)
```

[image]

Comment: But now the space between the tick marks is not even which is what I want.

Comment: And I want the points in the plot to be plotted at there true x,y coordinate.

Comment: The points are plotted at their true coordinates. I added a 100x multiplier to the data generator so they weren’t in a straight line near 1 since the axis values were so extreme. Play with the code and you will be able to get why you want. 
If you are just starting out with R, I’d recommend looking at ggplot as well.

Comment: The distance (visually) between -100 to 10 is not the same as -10 to 0. This is not what I want.

Comment: Having trouble knowing what you want. Evenly spaced tick marks which represent arbitrary intervals? Like 100 pixel distance in the axis represents -10 to 0 but above that 100 pixel distance represents 10 to 100? And linearly interpolated between the ticks?

Comment: See this for clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899146/how-to-make-custom-y-axis-scale-in-base-r/64899459#64899459